# Using a printer in Dosbox

Tags: printer, parallel-port, dosbox

I'm trying to find a way to run an old Dos based application that uses a printer connected to the parallel port, I don't think Dosbox supports lpt.

I am interested both in using that printer and in trying to emulate the printer somehow and connect a USB based printer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use one of the patched/forked versions of DOSBox that support printing.  [There are a few](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/SVN_Builds#Enhanced_SVN_builds).

One I've recently started using is [Taewoong's enhanced "ykhwong" version](http://ykhwong.x-y.net/) (as of writing, it was last updated Oct. 12. 2011):

> Included Patches:
>
> Direct3D with pixelshaders, OpenglHQ, Innovation, Glide, zip/7z
>   mount, Beep, NE2000 Ethernet, Graphis user interface (menu), Save/Load
>   states, Vertical sync, CPU flags optimization, Various DOS commands
>   (PROMPT VOL, LABEL, MOUSE, etc) and CONFIG.SYS commands (DEVICE,
>   BUFFERS, FILES, etc), Continuous turbo key, Core-switch key, Show
>   details (from menu bar), Nice DOSBox icon, Font patch (cp437), MAKEIMG
>   command, INTRO, Ctrl-break patch, DBCS support patch, Automatic mount,
>   **Printer output**, MT-32 emulation (MUNT), MP3CUE, Overscan border,
>   Stereo-swap, SDL_Resize, MemSize128, Internal 3dfx voodoo chip
>   emulation, Amstrad & PS/1 sound emulation, Fluidsynth soundfont
>   support, Timidity++ backend support, CGA w/ Monochrome Monitor
>   Support, Improve PC Speaker emulation accuracy patch, etc.

It allows redirecting LPT1 (through LPT3) to an actual LPT port, a printer file (.prn), or to the virtual printer.  The valid options in the Parallel/Dongle dialog are `reallpt`, `printer`, `file` and `disabled`.

If you set it up to send to the virtual printer, it can "print" to a graphic file (.PNG, .BMP, .PS), or to a Windows printer on the host (it pops up Windows a print dialog):

[image: DOSBox Printing]

Answer (score 8):

I somehow doubt that proper emulation of the parallel port was a priority for the DosBox devs.

Id did find this patch someone wrote in 2006:

http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=13117

which links to what is apparently a DosBox fork support forum?

http://qv90.hopto.org/bb/viewforum.php?f=3

Depending on how bad you want this, honestly, your best option might be getting older hardware and running DOS natively on it.

Alternately you might try running it in a true virtual machine like VirtualBox, VMWare, Xen, Virtual PC, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use [WinPrint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winprint/) for this:

> Takes standard printer output produced
>   by a DOS application, and forwards it
>   to a default Windows printer. Converts
>   code page, strips empty pages,
>   supports BOX DRAWINGS chars. Works on
>   all Windows platforms. Written in
>   Borland DELPHI.

It's specifically designed to help you print from old DOS programs onto new, USB connected printers.

Answer (score 4):

DOSBOX MegaBuild from here : http://home.arcor.de/h-a-l-9000/

Edit config file DOSBOX Megabuild like this

```
#parallel1=file append:C:\Users\user\filename.txt
```

Change to

```
parallel1=file dev:lpt1
```

Port capturing:

```
net use LPT1: \\computer-name\printer /persistent:yes
```

And you can print on USB Printer in Windows 7 64bit (and any other I think - without any printfil programs).

Comment: Only problem with MegaBuild is that the most recent is based off DosBox source code from 2010. MB6 is listed under "Obsolete SVN/CVS builds" in the DOSBox wiki. The ykhwong build was updated this year.